# Unable to read all the files reside in a network shared directory using SMB2 node module

Tags: node.js, smb

I am using SMB2 node module to read all the files around 2000 files reside in a network shared directory. But some how I am getting only 300 files information.
Is there any way, that I can loop through and get entire files information via readdir API of SMB2.

Here is code what I am using:

```
var SMB2 = require('smb2');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// create an SMB2 instance
var smb2Client1 = new SMB2({
    share: '\\\\Some.test.com\\test'
    , domain: '{domain}'
    , username: '{some user name}'
    , debug: false
    , password: '{password}'
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.listen(8000);
smb2Client1.readdir('Myfiles\\Somefolder', function (err, files) {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.send(files);
    });
```

Can someone please suggest how to get all the 2000 files information from this SMB2 node module ?